# Sort agenda items by link's text and not link's url

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I use `alpha-up` as the `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`. I have many hyperlinks in my task titles. And these items seem to be sorted by the url first (as a hyperlink is `[[url][title]]`. How do I change this behavior to actually sort on text only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `alpha-up`, use `user-defined-up` and define `org-agenda-cmp-user-defined` as a function that does what you want. The doc string for `org-agenda-cmp-user-defined` says:

```
This function must receive two arguments, agenda entry a and b.
If a>b, return +1.  If a<b, return -1.  If they are equal as seen by
the user comparison, return nil.
When this is defined, you can make ‘user-defined-up’ and ‘user-defined-down’
part of an agenda sorting strategy.
```

One way would be to modify the two arguments to delete the URL part of any link  that is encountered and then just do an alpha comparison on the results - something like this (N.B. untested and incomplete since it needs a definition of the `no-urls` function that would do the url erasing and which is left as an exercise, since I don't have the time to implement it atm):

```
(defun no-urls-string-cmp (a b)
   (let ((a-no-urls (no-urls a))
         (b-no-urls (no-urls b))
      (cond ((string-equal a-no-urls b-no-urls) nil)
            ((string-lessp a-no-urla b-no-urls) -1)
            (t 1))))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 
  (lambda () 
     (setq org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'no-urls-string-cmp)))
```

and modify `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` to use `user-defined-up` instead of `alpha-up`.